# Feature selection and y transformation

Tags: regression, feature-selection, data-transformation

My question is not specific to Python or how to solve the problem in code, but in principle about the best way of doing feature selection when considering y transformation. consider three models:

`Model-A: y~X (but the model uses log-transform)`: this is what we are interested in

`Model-B: log(y)~X`

`Model-C: y~X (no y transformation)`

`Model-B` and `Model-C` are obvious cases: If we model `log(y)~X`, we pass `(X,log(y))` to the feature selection algoirthm. If we model `y~X`, then we pas `(X,y)`.

Now the question is: if we are doing feature selection for Model-A (`y~X` but with y transformation in the model), then shall we apply our feature selection algorithm (Lasso in this case) to `(X,y)` or `(X,log(y))`?

To make my point clear, I use a scikit example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_gaussian_quantiles
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, y = make_gaussian_quantiles(random_state=0, n_features=10, n_samples=100)
st = StandardScaler()
X = st.fit_transform(X)
y= y*3+5
clf = linear_model.LassoCV(cv=5)


sfm = SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.01)
sfm.fit(X, y)
#sfm.fit(X, np.log(y))
n_features = 10

while n_features > 5:
    sfm.threshold += 0.01
    X_transform = sfm.transform(X)
    n_features = X_transform.shape[1]

print("selected features: ", n_features)

reg= linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Model-A: y~X (model uses log-transform): suppose that this is our final model
reg.fit(X_transform, np.log(y))
ypred = reg.predict(X_transform)
print("Model-A: ", round(metrics.r2_score(y, np.exp(ypred)),2))

 # Model-B: log(y)~X
reg.fit(X_transform, np.log(y))
ypred = reg.predict(X_transform)
print("Model-B: ", round(metrics.r2_score(np.log(y), ypred),2))

# Model-C: y~X (model uses no transformation)
reg.fit(X_transform, y)
ypred = reg.predict(X_transform)
print("Model-C: ", round(metrics.r2_score(y, ypred),2))
```

Output when using `sfm.fit(X, y)`:

```
selected features:  5
Model-A:  0.18
Model-B:  0.17
Model-C:  0.19
```

Output when using `sfm.fit(X, np.log(y))`:

```
selected features:  2
Model-A:  0.12
Model-B:  0.13
Model-C:  0.13
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the models are *identical,* because they are implemented by the same expression `reg.fit(X, np.log(y))`.  Could you explain how they differ?

Comment: @whuber, thanks, that's correct, but if we consider that e.g. `RFECV` checks for the R2 score at each round and then decides about the features to select, then their outcome will be different, and my question is since we don't want to select features based on model that uses `X~log(y)`, shall we actually fit the model using `fit.(X, y)` ? In other words, if the whole purpose is to get a better score using `Model-A`, what is the best way to do feature selection?

Comment: You will need to explain what these functions do so that people can understand what you are asking.  As it stands, although your question is not *about* Python, it is so extremely Python-centric that it is scarcely understandable.  In particular, the code exhibits no sign of "rounds" or of feature selection.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean and that's why I did not add the examples' code here. Let's focus on one that is familiar to everyone (I can edit the question if need be). LassoCV is Lasso where the lambda element will be automatically set. Considering that, LassoCV can be used to select k out of n features. The way it works is that you fit a model using LassoCV, you set a starting threshold and then increase it in a loop until Lasso selects the desired number of features. Now, in such a case, if my final model is `Model-A` shall I fit the Lasso with `(X,y)` or `(X,log(y))`?

Comment: That's much clearer--but doesn't correspond with anything found in your question as written.  The answer is "it depends" and there are a great many procedures for determining which, if either, is the model to use.  You might search our site for threads on log transformations of dependent variables, for instance.

Comment: thanks, but in my case, I DO know that log-transformation should be done on my target variable, so let's consider that's the case. Let's again consider the Lasso case. When we fit a model, Lasso gives the coefficients. Based on my understanding, that should be enough for Lasso to make a decision. Now that my final model actually transform and then inverse-transform the target, which way of fitting the target variable for the Lasso is the right way? log-transformed or untransformed? Does it still depend?

Comment: If you know the target should be transformed, why is there even a question to ask?  This looks like an inherent contradiction, leaving us to wonder what you're looking for.

Comment: That's why I showed the example code, in both cases the target is log-transformed, but the models will behave differently depending on whether the prediction will be inverse-transformed or not. The main issue (and my question) is since Lasso does not get into that stage  (it just fits the model and works with coefficients), then what is the right thing to do? shall we still pass the log-transformed target to it? what about the inherent differences between `Model-A` and `Model-B` in terms of the actual score

Comment: I'm lost: as I remarked initially, there are no apparent differences between the models and you seem to have confirmed that in your first comment.  Did you perhaps mean for Model A to be implemented with `reg.fit(X,y)` rather than `reg.fit(X, np.log(y))`?

Comment: Ok, first, I appreciate your time. I tried to avoid putting too much code here, but I realised that it has become confusing. So, please see the updated post. I think it's much clearer now.